# Eloquent's Many-to-Many inverse is not fetched

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 2 models namely Role and User models. With the following code respectively on each models:

Role.php:

```
public function users(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('\Models\User', 'rbac_user_roles','role_id','username');
}
```

..

User.php:

```
public function roles(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('\Models\RBAC\Role', 'rbac_user_roles','username','role_id');
}
```

but when I try to dump the data like so:

```
$model = Role::find( 1);
$model2 = User::find( 'test_user');

var_dump( $model->users->toArray() );
var_dump( $model2->roles->toArray() );
```

The $model->users->toArray() finds actual data while $model2->roles->toArray() returns nothing. Which is odd because I am pretty sure that the code works correctly. 
With this, I would like to ask, is there an effect if the primary key for the database is a string for eloquent? because I believe this is the culprit here. If so, what can i do to remedy the situation?

The situation needs/has the following conditions
-> Can't add a new column for index enabled auto-increment key for users table
-> All table and data is correctly setup, as the first var_dump() actually dumps the correct data.

Thanks,

Jan

EDIT:

I also tried the following in getting the User:

```
$model2 = User::where( 'username', 'test_user')->get()->first();
```

Note: The primary key for the table Users is a string

Comment: maybe column will be `id` instead of `username`. Can you recheck it pls?

Comment: Added an edit for this. The primary key used in the users table is a string field named "username"

Comment: do you define `username` is primary key in your model?

Comment: yes.

        $this->primaryKey = "username";

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, Eloquent is quite strict with non-increment primary keys. You should set the attribute for increments to false in the Eloquent Model like:

```
public $incrementing = false;
```